# Git push and Pull/fetch/rebase frequency - best practices

Tags: git, fetch, rebase, pull

I have been running into some trouble with git after pushing my changes to remote repository. I am the only person doing development so i haven't been doing Pull/fetch after pushing my commits because i didn't think it was necessary.

I read somewhere that you have to do a git pull/fetch after you do a push to remote so that you are synchronized with remote and your local repository is not telling you that *"you are ahead of ORIGIN/ by n commits"* when I use `git status` command.

I was under impression that when I push, my changes are committed to remote repo and there is no need to pull to my local repo since that is the master as has the latest changes. I don't understand why i get the *"you are ahead of ORIGIN/ by n commits"* message when I run `git status`. On top that when I did a git pull to try to rectify the problem right after doing the push to remote, git shows me that I have merges issues that i need to resolve in my local repo.

**I was able to get rid of it with a `git reset` but don't believe that is the correct way to resolve this!!**

Can someone help me with the correct sequence of commands that I need to execute starting from pushing to remote repo so that I don't run into these types of issues in the future.

This is my first stab at it:
`git push <to Remote Repo address> <to Remote Branch>`

//Assuming you are in the working directory already which one of these is the correct command to do next:

`git pull <from Remote Repo>` or `git fetch <from Remote Repo>` or `git pull --rebase`

Comment: If you already have been pushing commits, then why not just share the actual command(s) you have been running?  If you are really the only contributor to this branch, then I would not expect the errors you are getting.

Comment: @ Tim. So i use the Git Gui portion of the tool to do the pushes. Don't know if that would cause hiccups? It is same as 'git push <Arbitrary Location on GitLab> <Source Tracking Branch>. That's my actual push command.

Comment: AFAIK if you push your work and then pull, nothing should happen and you should not be getting any errors.  It could be difficult for someone here to debug your setup remotely like this.

Comment: @ Tim. Just as an expt. i re-cloned the repo to another local directory.

Comment: Your `git pull` looks wrong.  My guess is that you pulled the wrong branch into your local branch, hence the merge conflicts.  Use `git pull origin master`

Comment: Maybe i the directory I am in where I do a pull from is not the correct place to do a pull from. I am grasping at straws here...

Comment: No...the folder has nothing to do with it, so long as you are inside the `.git` folder.  And even if you weren't, `git pull` would not even be recognized as a command (typically).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148864/discussion-between-newb7777-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i first cloned my using

```
git clone <https://gitlab......git> 
cd <git cloned project directory> 
git branch -a
git checkout <branch name>
```

to check to see what happens when I fetch

```
git fetch --all
```

There were no changes to file and NO merge conflicts! 
then when i did a

```
git pull <https://gitlab......git>
```

or if I tried to do a

```
git pull origin master
```

there are merge conflicts. My mistake was at this point.

When I was doing my pull using 
`git pull origin master` the master repo was being pulled and mixed in with my local branch and was causing merge conflicts. there were no issues when i tried `git pull --all` or `git pull origin <correct branch name>`, and there were no merge conflicts.